# Is there a way to the Windows Calendar to update events when those are updated on Google Calendar?

Tags: sync, windows-11, calendar, google-calendar, windows-calendar

My Google Account is added in Windows Mail and set to sync my calendar. Currently, when a Google Calendar event gets edited so that it starts half an hour earlier, the default calendar in Windows 11 will still show me the old time.

This led in the past to me being late for an event so I try not to use Windows Calendar at all even when its Widget would otherwise be convenient. Is there a way to configure the Windows Calendar in a way that it actually updates events when those are updated in Google Calendar?

Comment: Make your time (time zone times) the same. You may need to adjust the time in Windows Mail .

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-get-google-calendar-on-windows-desktop-4687506

Comment: If you are importing the event with a calendar event file that’s a one time operation, you would have to synchronize the Google account itself, to get adjustments to events

Comment: @Moab : My calendar is setup to sync that way. It does mean that new events in the Google Calendar reach the Windows Calendar but currently does not handle changes in events.